# Animation Fade In and Fade out in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an UIImageView with an Animation and, in the UIView
I apply a fadeIn effect....
but i need to apply fade out when the UIImageView,
animated and  touched.

this is my code

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: delay, 
options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
    uiImageView.alpha = 1.0
    }
```

please answer me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.uiImageView.alpha = 0.0
}, completion: nil)
```